# pypyodbc ODBC Driver Manager Invalid string or buffer length error

Tags: odbc, driver, pypyodbc, motionbuilder

I am using pypyodbc from within a specialized called Motionbuilder, and recently I've been getting this strange error:

```
pypyodbc.Error: (u'HY090', u'[HY090] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length')
```

It doesn't happen every time, only sometimes.  Any ideas?

Comment: What ODBC driver are you using? Is it a special driver for MotionBuilder data, or is it for some other data source that you are trying to access from within MotionBuilder?

Comment: I'm using ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server, very standard.  Our Database is being accessed through a Python implementation within Motionbuilder.

Comment: Can I look at the code raising this error? Sound like there is a mal formed query here...

Comment: Definitely not a malformed Query.   Works in any other SQL application, even in other versions of Motionbuilder.  I think it has more to do with our ODBC driver and whatever program Python is running through.  We also have the problem with multiple different queries

Comment: hi, @NateonAjello Did you resolved the issue? thanks.

Comment: We ended up going back to PYODBC, which doesn't ever seem to have a problem.  We also had to recompile it against VS 2012 to use with the newer Motionbuilder and Maya.